# Python List : The different between the elements of a same list

Tags: python, list

Example:

```
Nums = [5,17,21,29]
Result = [12,16,24]
```

calculation

```
absolute(5-17) = 12
absolute(5-21) 
abs(5-24)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to subtract the first element with the rest,

```
Result = [abs(Nums[0] - item) for item in Nums[1:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> Nums = [5,17,21,29]
>>> [abs(Nums[0] - x) for x in Nums[1:]]
[12, 16, 24]
```

If you are using very large lists, you can avoid the shallow copy `[1:]` using `itertools.islice` (although this will almost never be necessary)

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [abs(Nums[0] - x) for x in islice(Nums, 1, None)]
[12, 16, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working only on the first item then you can use `iter()` to create an iterator, this will be more memory efficient and probably faster for large lists than @karthikr/@jamylak's version:

```
>>> lis = [5,17,21,29]
>>> it = iter(lis)
>>> item = next(it)
>>> [abs(item - x) for x in it]
[12, 16, 24]
```

Another solution that'll work for any index not just 0th:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> [abs(lis[n] - x) for i,x in enumerate(lis) if i != n]
[12, 16, 24]
>>> n = 1
>>> [abs(lis[n] - x) for i,x in enumerate(lis) if i != n]
[12, 4, 12]
```

Comment: +1 I would do this if the list was huge to avoid the shallow copy